# Queue Race Condition on Sql Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, race-condition

I have a process (tableProcess) UI where multiple people will analyze then.

The user workflow :

1 - User access the process UI that execute a SP to return how many process are available and opening the more recent one
I´m using

```
FROM tableProcess AS process WITH (UPDLOCK, READPAST)
```

In the same SP I´m updating the selected row with current Date.

2 - User confirm the action validating/invalidating the process.
Using a SP to select and update the process

The problem Im getting lock on entire tableProcess sometimes. Any workaround on that?

---

sp snippet

```
SELECT TOP (1) @Column1,@Column2,@Column3

FROM tableProcess AS process WITH (UPDLOCK, READPAST)   
WHERE (process.Date IS NULL)
ORDER BY process.AnalyseDate 

BEGIN TRAN
    UPDATE process
        SET process.Date = GETDATE()
            FROM tblProcess AS process 
            WHERE process.Column2 = @Column2;
COMMIT TRAN;
```

I have two indexes on that table:

-Colunm1(pk) (Unique, Clustered)

-Column2 (Non-unique, Non Clustered)

Comment: Include the `ROWLOCK` hint, use `SERIALIZABLE`, turn off lock escalation (`ALTER TABLE`), use app locks, enable and use snapshot isolation. It's hard to say which of these is appropriate for your use case.

Comment: You have to be very careful with the selection criteria and indexed if you need to ensure granular locking and concurrency when treating a table like a queue.  So, what is your WHERE clause, and what are your indexes?

Comment: I edited my quest with where and indexes. Thanks!